# Java.lang.Class.cast doesn't return a casted object

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I am trying to cast an object to its superclass using Java.lang.Class.cast but I get the same object. What can be the reason?

This is the code I'm running:

```
public static void parse(Object obj)
{
    // parse all super classes
    Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass().getSuperclass();
    if (!clazz.equals(prevClass))
    {
        prevClass = clazz;
        Object castedObj = clazz.cast(obj);
        parse(castedObj);   
    }
    fillObject(obj);
}
```

but when passing to `parse` an object of dynamic type B, where B extends A, `castedObj` is equal to `obj`.
But I want `castedObj` to be a new object of dynamic type A because the `parse` method relies on that fact (iterates on the fields of the dynamic type class).

Comment: What do you think casting does?

Comment: Casting != object-creation.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of `cast`. You don't get a new object, just the same object casted to another type. You don't change the dynamic type. You need to craft a special method for that.

Comment: For your purpose, if you have access to the `parse` method, I suggest you also pass the `Class` object to `parse`. So that it can use the class you want, and not just the dynamic type of its only argument.

Comment: Cast just means to treat the object as a different type, eg making particular methods visible to the compiler. And you never need to cast to a super type - you may always assign a subclass to a superclass variable

Comment: I guess the concept of casting in Java is different than in C++ in this sense. in C++ casting to a different object moves the pointer so it points to a "new" casted object. In Java it's just hushing the compiler? anyway thanks, I'll just pass the class type to parse()

Comment: @Torque_Roll in Java, there is no such thing as "casting an object". You can cast values (both primitives and references) but not objects.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to cast an object to its superclass using Java.lang.Class.cast but I get the same object.

That is exactly what is supposed to happen.

For reference types, a cast is simply a type check.  For example:

```
  A a = (A) b;
```

This says to check that `b` is-a `A` and the assign the reference so that we can refer to it as an `A` using `a`.

There is no object conversion going on.  No creation of new instances.  The value assigned to `a` is identical in every respect to the value in `b`.

The same also applies when you use reflection to do the typecasting.

Or to put it another way, the value returned by `getClass()` for a given object is always going to be the same ... no matter how you cast is.

---

It is not clear what you are trying to do in your code, but it we assume that `fillObject` is filling in fields that relate to a particular class, then you most likely need to pass the `Class` as an explicit parameter.  The true class of `obj` is always going to be the object's actual class ... irrespective of any casting.

Comment: `fillObject()` does exactly that, and passing the `Class` to it will probably be the solution. I thought that `Cast` will return a different pointer, in a similar manner to C++, but I thought wrong...

Comment: @Torque_Roll in C++, `class A {}; class B : public A{}; B* b = new B; A* a = (A*)b; cout << (a == b ? "true" : "false");` prints what?

Comment: @Torque_Roll - Your assertion that a C++ cast gives you a different pointer is ... puzzling.  Possibly you can do that with operator overloading, but AFAIK it doesn't happen with normal (non-overloaded) casts on object / pointer types.

Comment: @immibis You're right. All cast operations in C++ return the same pointer. I mistakenly thought otherwise because of the object layout. When you cast, you actually tell the program to look at a specific part of the object. It just uses the same pointer and knows where to look when you de-reference it...

Comment: @StephenC it can happen with multiple inheritance.

Comment: @immibis - I see.  Yet another reason for not liking multiple inheritance :-)